# Perforce workspace's altroot not being used by Ruby API

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have a Perforce workspace that uses altroot so it can be shared across Linux and Windows. The workspace root is set to the Windows path and the altroot is set to the Linux path. Both paths map and reference the same subdir.

On Linux, I can do a "p4 where" to a file under the workspace and the file's local path is correct, properly using the altroot path. However, when I do a run_where from ruby for the same file, the file's local path is returned as the Windows path (using the workspace root dir instead of the altroot).

Everything works as expected on Windows, but that may just be because it's also using the root path with run_where from Ruby, which is the Windows path.

Is there a way to get the ruby API to recognize the altroot?

Thank you,
Chris Harper